# How to write delete method using POST request - REST - Nest JS

Tags: javascript, rest, post, crud, nestjs

How to delete an id or a record in database using post request in api

***Delete one guide from database***

```js
@Delete('/:id')
deleteGuide(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.guidesService.deleteGuide(id);
}
```

Comment: What does your GuidesService look like? What database and or ORM are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to use a POST request or a DELETE request? The code snippet shows an HTTP DELETE but your question pertains to an HTTP POST, which is causing a bit of confusion.

Comment: async deleteGuide(id: string): Promise<void>{
  const result = await this.guideRepository.delete(id);
  
 if(result.affected === 0){
   throw new NotFoundException(`Guide with ID "$id" not found`);
 }
}

This is how my GuidesService looks like and also I'm using PostgreSql @KimKern

Comment: I'm trying to use POST request to delete the record in the database @JayMcDoniel

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit? You need to change your decorator to a `@Post(':id')` instead of the DELETE one if you want to use a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
@Post('/:id')
deleteGuide(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.guidesService.deleteGuide(id);
}
```